# How do I adjust alsamixer?

Tags: command-line, alsa

How I chage alsamixer in the command line so that I can fine tune alsamixer and get rid of some white noise? Right now it looks like this.

[image: alsamixer.png]

But from what I have read I need it to look like this.
[image: alsamixer2]

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help me.

Comment: try pressing `tab` key a few times

Comment: @blvdeer, I tried your suggestion but I got this error message-"This sound device does not have any capture controls. It sounds like I may need to find a different way to eliminate the white noise. So thanks anyway, you too, rajenupula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here some of the commands can help you.

- Use the right and left arrow keys to navigate through the sliders.
- At the bottom of each slider you see either 00 or MM. Toggle these with the <kbd>M</kbd> key. MM means muted, 00 is enabled.
- Use the up and down arrow keys or the <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys to control the sliders. <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> move the sliders in increments of five, and the End key resets to zero. When there are two channels controlled by one slider, <kbd>Q</kbd> increases the left channel and <kbd>Z</kbd> decreases. <kbd>E</kbd> increases the right channel, and <kbd>C</kbd> decreases.
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to see all the system information on your sound cards. If you have more than one sound card press <kbd>F6</kbd> to display a sound card chooser.

[Source](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7134/2)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your current soundcard supports, as its HDMI its showing S/PDIF.
Try pressing **F5** to display all options that the soundcard supports.

You can also change sound device/card with the **F6** key